# How to find text with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Guys I need to know how to find a text with Selenium, this one for example:

```
Test
```

I can get the text with the following code:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[text()="Test"]'))).text
```

But I need to get a text in the following format:

```
"Key" "email@gmail.com"
```

I need to be able to get the above text, remembering the email and password may be different depending on the case, so I would like to get the full value of the string from the `.com` of the string, since the email will always have a .com, so in this case , I need to be able to find the .com and after finding me return the full value of the string.

Comment: Can we have some sample HTML code ? would be much easy to figure out how to get the ` full value of the string from the .com`

Comment: also remember that `""` is a text node, not HTML DOM node. also `.text()` could represent the node, but one can not parse that with Selenium

Comment: @cruisepandey I didn't put it because it's complicated to explain what I'm doing lol, it's easier for me to just explain the classroom, basically I'm getting a text that is in double quotes and I don't use selectors because the id or class are always dynamic, so I need to a way to get the text from a part of the text that will always have, which in this case is `.com`

Comment: there can be different tag that will help us to determine this dynamic nature, unfortunately you won't be able to write xpath while working with text nodes.

Comment: @cruisepandey I've already discovered the cause that makes the element dynamic, but it's a browser behavior, there's no way I can prevent it, at most prevent it a little, and it's not feasible, I need to get the text by injecting some javascript code then, since I don't it will be possible to use the `.text()` method

Comment: I referred xpath `some-node/text()`, not `.text()` from selenium, I won't be able to answer this question due to lack of HTML code, which OP has not shared yet.

Comment: @cruisepandey Ok, to understand what I'm doing... I'm running the following code in the `chromium terminal --no-sandbox --disable-translate --disable-in-process-stack-traces --remote-debugging-port= 8081 https://discord.com/channels/395582581125497408/395582581124497412 after that I open the browser at localhost:8081` there will be a devtool window that will be displayed even without you pressing F12, but pressing F12 you will see 2 devtools, in the first devtool ( which you don't need to press F12 to be displayed)

Comment: i type the following javascript in `console var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  iframe.onload = function(){ var ifrLocalStorage = iframe.contentWindow.localStorage;  token = ifrLocalStorage.getItem('token');  email = ifrLocalStorage.getItem('email_cache');  console.log(token,email);  };  document.body.appendChild(iframe);` after that my discord token and email will be displayed, I need to get this text (token and email) with Selenium

Comment: I hope you know how to share HTML code ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `contains` in xpath to find a text that has `.com`. You can also use `ends-with`. The `xpath` would be something like this:

```
 //*[contains(text(),'.com')]
```

Or

```
 //*[ends-with(text(),'.com')]
```

Comment: Selenium can't find it, is it because my text is in quotes?

Comment: It will never locate the element, since .com is not a plain text instead it is a text node

Comment: @Dkns- Even if the `text` of element is in `" "` double quotes, I was able to extract complete 'text` using `contains`. I can show you an example if you want.

Comment: @pmadhu : I would like to know when you inspect `//*[contains(text(),'.com')]` in HTML DOM, and when we have a text node, were you able to see any matches ? It's highly unlikely, xpath 2.0 can do that, but Selenium does not have support for V2.0, it still usages V1.0